# Problemas con Menu Top Position Fixed

Tags: html, css

Crée un menu con `position fixed` pero cuando le doy al scroll para bajar y ver mi página, el menu se baja con mi scroll y me deja un `margen-top` ¿cómo puedo resolverlo? Ayuda, aquí esta mi código

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px){ header nav {position: fixed;width: 70%;     height: 100%;margin: 0;left: -100%;z-index: 99;}

    header nav ul li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        z-index: 99
    }
    header nav ul li:hover{
        color:red;
    }

    .menu_bar{
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ccc;
        z-index: 99

    }
    .menu_bar .bt-menu{
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #bc2045;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 25px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 99;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Podrías añadir el HTML que estás utilizando para poder reproducir el error que comentas? Si [edit] la pregunta puedes, mediante Cntrl+M insertar código para realizar un ejemplo reproducible. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: hola que tal.. es que mi codigo html es muy largo y el css tambien por eso coloque solo ese fregmento

Comment: Intenta minimizar lo máximo posible tu HTML y tu CSS para que solamente se vea la parte de código afectada por tu error. Ahora mismo, es imposible ayudarte ya que podría haber n soluciones posibles (al no tener un ejemplo claro de lo que te pasa).

Answer (score 1):

Si el problema es el margen que te queda en la parte superior deberías añadir un top: 0px; en el selector header nav

Comment: ya lo coloque lo que me dices y no me funciona

Comment: El top: 0px; en aplicado a un contenedor fijo (position: fixed) no falla. Quizás sea porque está dentro de un @query y solo se aplica cuando la pantalla es menor a 800px. ¿Hay alguna forma de que pongas más código para poder ver el error?

Comment: dejame ver como optimizo el codigo para subirlo